# UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum crash stack trace / error log: What is the crash?

Tags: iphone, uiimagepickercontroller, crash-reports

Can someone tell me what type of crash this is? (i.e. Out of memory?)

I received this crash log but I have no idea what the problem is.
Could I wrap the code in a try catch block and at least handle this gracefully.
I don't have any steps from a user and I can't get my iOS device to crash in this code.

```
Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.assetsd.sharedPersistentStoreCoordinator
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3339f32c __pthread_kill + 8
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x376e7f54 pthread_kill
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x376e0fe4 abort
3   libc++abi.dylib                 0x33384f64 abort_message + 40
4   libc++abi.dylib                 0x33382346 _ZL17default_terminatev + 18
5   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x332b72dc _objc_terminate
6   libc++abi.dylib                 0x333823be _ZL19safe_handler_callerPFvvE + 70
7   libc++abi.dylib                 0x33382372 __cxxabiv1::__terminate(void (*)()) + 2
8   libc++abi.dylib                 0x33382882 __cxa_call_terminate + 46
9   libc++abi.dylib                 0x333832ac __gxx_personality_sj0 + 968
10  libunwind.dylib                 0x33170a7e unwind_phase2 + 66
11  libunwind.dylib                 0x33170c0e _Unwind_SjLj_Resume + 122
12  PhotoLibraryServices            0x324d99ea -[PLPhotoLibrary(Protected) loadDatabase]
13  PhotoLibraryServices            0x324a217e -[PLPhotoLibrary initWithPath:canTriggerDatabaseUpdate:]
14  PhotoLibraryServices            0x324e919e __42+[PLSharedPhotoLibrary sharedPhotoLibrary]_block_invoke_0
15  libdispatch.dylib               0x347c5570 dispatch_once_f$VARIANT$up
16  PhotoLibraryServices            0x324e915c +[PLSharedPhotoLibrary sharedPhotoLibrary]
17  PhotoLibraryServices            0x324aa068 __withSavedPhotosAlbumUUID_block_invoke_0
18  libdispatch.dylib               0x347c5570 dispatch_once_f$VARIANT$up
19  PhotoLibraryServices            0x324a9430 withSavedPhotosAlbumUUID
20  PhotoLibraryServices            0x324a9372 PLSaveImageToCameraRoll
21  UIKit                           0x30b9f1ce UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum
```

Here is the code:

```
- (void) imagePickerController: (UIImagePickerController *) picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo: (NSDictionary *) info {

NSString *mediaType = [info objectForKey: UIImagePickerControllerMediaType];
UIImage *originalImage, *editedImage, *imageToSave;

// Handle a still image capture
if (CFStringCompare ((CFStringRef) mediaType, kUTTypeImage, 0)
    == kCFCompareEqualTo) {

    editedImage = (UIImage *) [info objectForKey:
                               UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage];
    originalImage = (UIImage *) [info objectForKey:
                                 UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];

    if (editedImage) {
        imageToSave = editedImage;
    } else {
        imageToSave = originalImage;
    }

    if (imagePickerSourceType == UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera) {
        // Save the new image (original or edited) to the Camera Roll
        UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum (imageToSave, nil, nil , nil);
    }

}
```

**UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum (imageToSave, nil, nil , nil);**

I cannot get it to crash on my device or I would have a better chance of figuring this out. This is a crash log from iTunes Connect.

Comment: could you post the code line where this crash happens?

Comment: Could you put the code where it crash ?

Comment: Oh please put in a breakpoint and find out where your code is crashing.. If it's the line with `UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum` maybe you want to save something wrong or unacceptable..?

Comment: Having the same problem. Did you ever discover the cause?

Comment: No I did not figure out the problem. I couldn't reproduce any crash on my device and I couldn't tell from the crash log what the specific problem is.